# Draw on a map with mouse

Tags: ros, rviz, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for a user to demonstrate trajectories on a map. I'm using RViz for everything, so an RViz would be excellent but other options are ok too. The map is coming from `map_server` as `nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid` I want the user to click and drag to draw on the map, and I want to be able to produce a standard `nav_msgs::Path` from it. Any ideas how to do this?

Do I have to make my own application from the ground up for this? Or can rviz be hacked to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238009/draw-on-a-map-with-mouse/) by [petermitrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/21252/petermitrano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2016-06-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [C3MX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25486/c3mx/) on 2016-10-07**:
+1 Here ! , I also want to draw things (like polygons) on the map , to define prohibited area easily without image editors and save it as a new file for global costmap. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

May not be what you need though, use `Publish Point` tool on RViz (surprisingly I don't find it described anywhere on ROS wiki). It's usually on the top bar of RViz. See [this video](http://opensource-robotics.tokyo.jp/?p=1579&lang=en) that shows placing multiple `Publish Point`s in a closed loop draws polygon.

> I want the user to click and drag to draw on the map, and I want to be able to produce a standard nav_msgs::Path from it. Any ideas how to do this?

Not entirely sure, but with [frontier_exploration](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration) package you can specify a region for the robot to explore, and the software computes a path to that location. In the same link [I mentioned above](http://opensource-robotics.tokyo.jp/?p=1579&lang=en) is a bit more about the package.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1